# Alternative VAR($p$) representation

Tags: time-series, self-study, vector-autoregression

Consider VAR($p$) model in the form
$$y_{it} = \sum_{k=1}^{p}\sum_{j=1}^n\alpha_{ijk}y_{jt-k} + \epsilon_{it}, \;\; i=1,\dots,n.$$

In a paper I read it is stated

> Consider the following regression representation of $y_{it}$ as a function of lags of all series as well as the contemporaneous realizations of all other series in the panel, that is $$y_{it} = \sum_{k=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^n\beta_{ijk}y_{jt-k} + \sum_{h=1\\ h\neq i}^n\gamma_{ih}y_{ht} + e_{it}.$$

I understand the purpose of this representation but I wonder why this representation is equivalent to the usual one?